# Is it possible to dynamically update a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea and a button which removes the selected text (from textArea).

```
RemoveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){                
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String test = textArea.getSelectedText();
        textArea.replaceSelection("");                  
    }           
});
```

The code above works fine, however, when I click the button the text shows like this:

[image]

Here I removed the first and third Test. How can I make this dynamically update so it displays the text without gaps?

I could call a method re-populate the JTextArea with the remaining elements but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Err, make sure to include the line break inside the text selection? I have the feeling you're using a JTextArea where you should use a JList or a JTable.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to switch to a JList, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like

```
textArea.setText(textArea.getText().replaceAll("\n\n",""));
```

However, a `TextArea` may not be the best component for that kind of use. A `Jlist` could be more fitted if you want to store input on different lines.